# Generate individual data distributions using mean and standard deviation data from a data frame in R

Tags: r, normal-distribution

I have a `data.frame` in `R`, containing several categorical variables, each with its own mean and standard deviation. I want to generate values from a normal data distribution for each categorical variable defined by these values and generate individual `data.frames` for each discrete categorical variable.

Here's some dummy data

```
dummy_data <- data.frame(VARIABLE = LETTERS[seq( from = 1, to = 10 )],
                         MEAN = runif(10, 5, 10), SD = runif(10, 1, 3))

dummy_data

   VARIABLE     MEAN       SD
1         A 6.278751 1.937093
2         B 6.384247 2.487678
3         C 9.017496 2.003202
4         D 5.125994 1.829517
5         E 9.525213 1.914513
6         F 9.004893 2.734934
7         G 9.780757 2.511341
8         H 5.372160 1.510281
9         I 6.240331 2.796826
10        J 8.478280 2.325139
```

What I'd like to do from here, is to generate individual data.frames for each row, with each data.frame containing a normal distribution based on the `MEAN` and `SD` columns.

So, for example, I'd have a separate data.frame that contained....

```
A <- subset(dummy_data, VARIABLE == 'A')
A <- data.frame(rnorm(20,  A$MEAN, A$SD))

A

   rnorm.20..A.MEAN..A.SD.
1                 5.131331
2                 9.388104
3                 8.909453
4                 5.813257
5                 5.353137
6                 7.598521
7                 2.693924
8                 5.425703
9                 8.939687
10                9.148066
11                4.528936
12                7.576479
13                8.207456
14                6.838258
15                6.972061
16                7.824283
17                6.283434
18                4.503815
19                2.133388
20                7.472886
```

The real data I'm working with is much larger than ten rows, and so I don't want to subset the whole thing to generate the individual `data.frames` if I can help it.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `data.table`:

```
library(data.table)
result     <- setDT(dummy_data)[, .(sample=rnorm(20, mean=MEAN, sd=SD)), by=.(VARIABLE)]
list.of.df <- split(result, result$VARIABLE)
```

Answer (score 2):

What about a solution using `dplyr`?:

```
library(dplyr)

#A dataframe containing all the information
Huge_df <- dummy_data %>% group_by(VARIABLE) %>% summarise(SIMULATED = rnorm(20, MEAN, SD))

#You can then split the dataframe if needed:
Splitted <- split.data.frame(Huge_df, "VARIABLE")
```

If you then need to save every individual dataframe, or do something else with them, you can always unlist the `Splitted` object

Answer (score 0):

You can put everything into a list, then return all the elements in the list to the global environment (if desired, or keep in the list):

```
set.seed(123)
dummy_data <- data.frame(VARIABLE = LETTERS[seq( from = 1, to = 10 )],
                         MEAN = runif(10, 5, 10), SD = runif(10, 1, 3))

# put all the values into a list
list_dist <- vector(mode = "list", length = nrow(dummy_data))
for(i in 1:nrow(dummy_data)){
  list_dist[[i]] <- data.frame(values = rnorm(20, dummy_data[i,2], dummy_data[i,3]))
}
# name the list elements 
names(list_dist) <- dummy_data$VARIABLE

# or more detailed names, for instance, 
# names(list_dist) <- paste0(dummy_data$VARIABLE, "_Distribution")

#return all list values to the global environment
list2env(list_dist,globalenv())
```